# Bot Framework builder.prompt.text

Tags: node.js, frameworks, bots, builder

I have problem with builder.prompt.text, when user response, then will redirect to main "/" dialog, it wont go to next waterfall/dialog

Question is what may cause that?

My bot runs every day, certain time and checks database which user needs questioning and then will create dialog

im using latest bot builder dependency.
Thanks

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');

.....

var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
});

// Create chat bot
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: AppId,
    appPassword: AppPass
});

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

.....

bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session) {
        console.log(session);
    }
]);

....

bot.beginDialog(createAddress(user), '/users');

.....

bot.dialog('/users', [
    function (session) {
        session.sendTyping();
        session.options.logger.isEnabled = true;
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Question comes here.");
        // after response goes to dialog "/"
    },
    function (session, results) {

        // wont come here
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Question comes here1.");

    }
]);
```

Comment: Please add some code, and explain what you've tried so far

Comment: Added little code example